# Passing parameter to angular directive in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have the following directive. I am trying to pass the class name that needs to be toggled when the link/button is clicked. I keep getting undefined in debug console. HostListener takes array of args - i guess i am not sure how to pass them and cant seem to find example of it.

```
   @Directive({
  selector: '[appSidebarToggler]'
})
export class SidebarToggleDirective {

  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event', '$tobeToggledClassName'])

  toggleOpen($event: any, $tobeToggledClassName: any) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    console.log("class to be toggled is - >" + $tobeToggledClassName);
    console.log("ref - >" + this.elementRef);
    document.querySelector(tobeToggledClassName).classList.toggle('sidebar-hidden');

  }
}
```

and i am using it like this in my component :

```
<a class="" href="#" sidebarToggler tobeToggledClassName="sideMenu">&#9776;</a>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it like:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event', '$event.target.getAttribute("tobeToggledClassName")'])
```

[**Example 1**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uX91uBUuT45FtjCVSTcS?p=preview)

or use injected `ElementRef`

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute("tobeToggledClassName")
```

**[Example 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gx8SHBjtkMzrxholRl9i?p=preview)**

or inject `@Attribute` in contstructor of your directive:

```
constructor(...@Attribute('tobeToggledClassName') private tobeToggledClassName: string) {}
```

**[Example 3](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ugf0EHTGlbXasfq57ZaN?p=preview)**

Comment: + 1 I personally like 1st one, all three are nicer way. *Question* What will happen incase I want to pass some dynamic value to `HostListner` function.?

Comment: @PankajParkar  I don't argue :) I just was looking for something else than standart Input :) I upvoted you too

Comment: @PankajParka For dynamic value we can use `[attr.name]` https://plnkr.co/edit/umXy6QMtO4dspRO1BRgo?p=preview So we don't relay on @Input property and we have minus one line in our class )

Comment: No, I don't meat in that way. I'm curious to know, I'm 100% sure you must know better way

Answer (score 4):

You could pass class name inside `Input` binding of directive. You can easily retrieve a value of binding at any instance.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSidebarToggler]'
})
export class SidebarToggleDirective {
  @Input() tobeToggledClassName: string;
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])

  toggleOpen($event: any) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    console.log("class to be toggled is - >" + this.tobeToggledClassName);
    console.log("ref - >" + this.elementRef);
    document.querySelector(this.tobeToggledClassName).classList.toggle('sidebar-hidden');

  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<a class="" href="#" sidebarToggler tobeToggledClassName="sideMenu">&#9776;</a>
OR
<a class="" href="#" sidebarToggler [tobeToggledClassName]="'sideMenu'">&#9776;</a>
```